# Ruby on Rails: 3d Chart with HighCharts and Chartkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, highcharts, chartkick

I'm trying to show a 3d chart with chartkick + HighCharts.

I use this code:

```
<%= pie_chart @array.pluck(:title, :percent), adapter: 'highcharts' height: '300px', library: {chart: { options3d: {enabled: true,alpha: 45,beta: 0}},plotOptions: {pie: {depth: 35}}}%>
```

But I get a normal Pie Chart (not 3d).

I download https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js into vendor/assets/javascripts.

I tried to require in my application.js

```
//= require highcharts/highcharts-3d
```

Which causes `couldn't find file 'highcharts/highcharts-3d' with type 'application/javascript'`

Thank you guys.

Comment: What doesn't work? How doesn't it work? What error is it giving you? Please address these in your question so you receive more complete answers.

Comment: If I require highcharts/highcharts-3d in mi application.js I get this error:
couldn't find file 'highcharts/highcharts-3d' with type 'application/javascript'

Where can I find this file?

Comment: The highcharts.js file isn't highcharts-3d.js — you need highcharts-3d.js, or whatever similar, and/or you need to specify you want the 3d piechart to chartkick, and/or create your own adapter.

Comment: Looks like https://github.com/ankane/chartkick/issues/211 may be of help.

Comment: I found that issue by searching chartkick issues for `3d`

Comment: I find it here:
https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.js

Thank you for all guys!